# Best data type for hex values in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, hex, sqldatatypes

What is the best data type for storing hex values in an Oracle database?  With a 33-byte value like this:

```
0x54906a620d3c1e82c8e812b0f8d1214beafc05c74820c1dd3675b0c38f4a83aa
```

is there a preferred data type that will:

a) use minimal disk space, and
b) be queryable via that full string?

To store that value, I can use `VARCHAR2(132)`.  But does that use 132 bytes on the disk, or 33 bytes?

If it uses 132 bytes on the disk, then what data type could I use to store only 33 bytes?  And will that datatype allow me to use the full string in a query, like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '0x54906a620d3c1e82c8e812b0f8d1214beafc05c74820c1dd3675b0c38f4a83aa'
```

or would it require me to convert my 132 characters to 33 bytes before using in a SQL query?

Comment: varchar2 does not store more than what the size of the actual data is.  just use varchar2 with no worries. create an index on it.

Comment: @OldProgrammer But if "a8" is a hex value of a single byte, will varchar2 store 1 byte, or will it store 2 bytes (one for the letter 'a' and one for the number 8)?

Answer (score 3):

> if "a8" is a hex value of a single byte, will varchar2 store 1 byte, or will it store 2 bytes (one for the letter 'a' and one for the number 8)?

The latter, if you store it as a string.

You can store as [RAW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-4FD497DD-3331-4C25-9147-3CEBEFDBFF22):

> These data types are intended for binary data or byte strings.

For example:

```
create table test (hex_value raw(128));
```

```
insert into test (hex_value) values (hextoraw('54906a620d3c1e82c8e812b0f8d1214beafc05c74820c1dd3675b0c38f4a83aa'));
```

```
select hex_value, dump(hex_value)
from test
where hex_value = hextoraw('54906a620d3c1e82c8e812b0f8d1214beafc05c74820c1dd3675b0c38f4a83aa');
```

| HEX_VALUE | DUMP(HEX_VALUE) |
| --- | --- |
| 0x54906A620D3C1E82C8E812B0F8D1214BEAFC05C74820C1DD3675B0C38F4A83AA | Typ=23 Len=32: 84,144,106,98,13,60,30,130,200,232,18,176,248,209,33,75,234,252,5,199,72,32,193,221,54,117,176,195,143,74,131,170 |

You can see from the dump that it is stored in 32 bytes. (The RAW value is converted implicitly to a string for display, and the `0x` is being added by db<>fiddle; other clients won't show that, and might not show RAW values at all.)

You can convert back to a string if you need to, which will then be 64 bytes:

```
select rawtohex(hex_value), dump(rawtohex(hex_value)) from test;
```

| RAWTOHEX(HEX_VALUE) | DUMP(RAWTOHEX(HEX_VALUE)) |
| --- | --- |
| 54906A620D3C1E82C8E812B0F8D1214BEAFC05C74820C1DD3675B0C38F4A83AA | Typ=1 Len=64: 53,52,57,48,54,65,54,50,48,68,51,67,49,69,56,50,67,56,69,56,49,50,66,48,70,56,68,49,50,49,52,66,69,65,70,67,48,53,67,55,52,56,50,48,67,49,68,68,51,54,55,53,66,48,67,51,56,70,52,65,56,51,65,65 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DwH4qn9j)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.  Is there a simple query "LIKE" syntax for querying values in hex datatype?  SELECT hex_value FROM test WHERE hex_value LIKE '%....'

Also, unrelated, but I was college roommates with an Alex Poole.  He was wild and fun and awesome!

Comment: Ha, wasn't me then *8-) And no, I think you'd either have to convert both sides to strings; or maybe use [`utl_raw.substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-B10F57A2-B9EB-4236-84C1-3CEF0D79C122) to get the number of bytes you want to compare?

Comment: What a shame! I though you two were really *long lost* roommates :)

Comment: @MichaelC Note that conversion to string and `like` may provide false positives. For example `0x0110` will match `rawtohex(your_col) like '%11%'` while it doesn't have this byte.

Comment: @astentx - That's a good point.  Thank you for highlighting that (potential false positives)